# Django environment variables in MAC - os.environ.get() returns None

Tags: python, django

Working on Django project, I am at the production stage, trying to hide SECRET_KEY before production using environment variables in MAC computer. I have added secret keys in .bash_profile from Terminal using nano. However when I call the saved variable (secret key) on the terminal, I got key value using:

```
echo $variable
```

Then i tried calling secret key variable in settings.py in Django project using:

```
secret_key = os.environ.get('variable(secret key) from .bash_profile)
```

However, it is returning None .

Please can someone help me with this? I have tried solutions on here but still have not resolved issue. I know the new MAC update Catalina uses zprofile but i do not know how my issue is linked to this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `'saved variable(secret key) from .bash_profile)` accomplishes, but if you are exporting the variable properly in your `.bash_profile`, then the following should work:

```
os.environ['variable']
```

Comment: saved variable is variable.

Comment: @ECHO what value do you get when you run `echo $variable`, and what do you get when you run my code?

Comment: In the Terminal, it returns the variable but when i run code in Django, I get None.